# Read Http post parameters from Android in JSP

Tags: android, jsp

I'm making an app, that should make post request to my jsp. I made everything what was written in examples, but it isn't working still. I catch the request on the server, but all parameters return `null`.

Android code

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
String responseString = null;
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);

try {
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("group", group));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("increment", String.valueOf(additionalPoints)));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

JSP code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<%
    String group = request.getParameter("group");
    String incrementStr = request.getParameter("increment");
%>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

**Android code**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try
        {
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);

            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            paris.add(new BasicNameValuePair("group", group));
            paris.add(new BasicNameValuePair("increment", String.valueOf(additionalPoints)));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**JSP code**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
</head>
<%
    String group=request.getParameter("group");
    String increment=request.getParameter("increment");
%>

</html>
```

Comment: It's not working still. The parameters are null. Is your code working for you?

Comment: no I have not tested sorry...but I have found this article
http://blog.csdn.net/xialei3233/article/details/8100142 I hope it can help you

Comment: No that code will not work for him. He will have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException` as that code should be placed in an AsyncTask or thread. And what is different from your code???

Comment: Yes I have it in `AsyncTask` and I get the request on server side. The only problem is that parameters are always `null`.